# I have a string "name1 name2 name3 name4 name5". How can I go about separating these in a way that variable1 = name1 | variable2 = name2 etc.?

Tags: lua

Althought I stated that my string is "name1 name2 name3 name4 name5", I don't actually know my string and want a way to apply this to any string. "this" being a way to cut a string with words separated by a space into different variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string.gmatch` to get each word by using a pattern that describes one or more non-whitespace characters `"%S"` and add them into a table.

```
local text = "name1 name2 name3 name4 name5"
local words = {}
for word in text:gmatch("%S+") do
  table.insert(words, word)
end

local variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4, variable5 = table.unpack(words)
```

I wouldn't recommend using the last line as you can simply address the words through their table index. Having variable names for every single word is not practical for high or unknown numbers of words.

So just use `words[5]` instead of `variable5` in your example

Comment: Thanks for the help!